# How to install the apt-get command, when it's itself been removed?

Tags: 11.10, apt, dpkg, wget

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Asus tf101 and wanted to strip it down a little bit
removed the desktop environment and any application that comes with it.

By doing this I accidentally removed `apt-get` (don't ask).

Now I want to reinstall it, but I can't find a single forum post or blog issuing this problem and I have no idea how to do it.

Can somebody please help me?

(And please don't ask why I don't just install Ubuntu server, installing Ubuntu on this thing was a pain already.)

Comment: Why didn't you install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? 11.10 support ends soon but LTS releases get a way longer support window.

Comment: @japzone Fortunately, 11.10 can be upgraded to 12.04 LTS quite easily. (vinniethepooh: I recommend this; after sometime next month you won't even get security updates for 11.10.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, I was just wondering why he was running 11.10, but he replied below saying it was an Android tablet port, so that explains it.

Comment: @EliahKagan i am doing the upgrade right now, just had to free up some space, my root is just 2 gigs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why 11.10? That's going out of support in a month... I'll actually be easier and faster to reinstall, using a newer version.

If you really want to stick to the old version, download http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.16~exp5ubuntu13_i386.deb (32 bit) or http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.16~exp5ubuntu13_amd64.deb (if you have a 64-bit system) and install with `sudo dpkg -i apt_*.deb`.

Comment: thanks for the links and the really quick response! 11.10 because it's actually an android tablet and i found this tutorial using 11.10. which i certainly couldn't install myself. wanted do upgrade to 12.10 but didn't have enough space left, that's why i wanted to strip it down completely and install lubuntu-desktop. it's arm actually..

Comment: uname -m outputs armv7l

Comment: I don't know the exact url to the arm package. You should look at your sources.list to find the mirror, then go to that mirror, to the pool/main/a/apt/ directory and download the correct .deb file for armv7l (version 0.8.16~exp5ubuntu13).

Comment: This may be the one: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.8.16~exp5ubuntu13_armel.deb

Comment: thanks! so here's the mirror http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/a/apt/ . i guess i just download all the debs labeled with 0.8.16~exp5ubuntu13_armel

Comment: okay sorry didn't see the your last post, so here's my next problem... i removed all packages labeled with ubuntu... i know.. now it gives me the error apt depends on ubuntu-keyring. i guess i just install the deb from here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-keyring/ but which is the right one? and do the same for every error that follows

Comment: Don't grab packages from archive.ubuntu.com, but from ports.ubuntu.com. And grab the newest version that's older than the release date for Ubuntu 11.10 (october 13, 2011)

Comment: yeah sorry posted the wrong link! that did the trick! thank you so much for your really quick solution and your patience!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. By the way, it's customary on this site to 'accept' the correct answer to your question by clicking on the tickmark underneath its score.